# Print Sum of Array Values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find and print the total of the array, but it only prints the array. Any suggestions on where I went wrong?

```
var c = new Array(
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
    "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
    "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
    "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
    "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", 
    "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", 
    "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", 
    "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", 
    "98", "99", "100"
) 

var total = 0;

for ( var i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
{

    total += c [ i ];
}

document.writeln( "<p>The total of array c is: " + total + "</p>" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of strings, so Javascript uses the `+` operator as a concatenation. You need to change the values to numbers first.

Try this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
  total += (+c[i]);
}
```

The unary `+` forces Javascript to treat the value as a number;

There's a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dr10srer/)

Comment: Another alternative is to use `parseInt(c[i], 10)`.

Comment: 1st:  Thank you for making my original post look like code.  & that worked perfectly!!!  I haven't came across that technique yet, but nothing I could find in the book was working.  Thanks.